# Making a username unique for database insertion

Tags: coldfusion, url-rewriting

I am inserting unique names into a database table that have been submitted by users as their username.

When a name is submitted via a form, my ColdFusion code checks the database to see if that name already exists. If it does exist then it makes it the username unique by adding a sequential number  to it.

My issue is that while checking the database for a name conflict is easy enough, I also don't want the name to conflict with the name of any folder, .cfm file, or .html file in my site.

At the moment I am using a simple `ListFindNoCase('folder1,folder2,folderN', username)` function to check for conflicts but this is done manually. Whenever I add a new file or folder to the site I have to add it to this list. Its not a good way to do it.

How can I get a list of all the contents in my site and make it into a delimited list and then do the `ListFindNoCase()` function to check if the username is in that list of contents? Is this even a pragmatic way to go about it?

Comment: What is the motivation behind this request?  Also, what happens if you add a file to your site that conflicts with a username in your db?

Comment: The motivation is to do with URL rewriting. If you go to facebook.com/friends then where will it go? Should it go a profile page for the sitcom 'Friends' or should it go to a default document in the folder named 'friends' in the site? I write usernames to a table which then tells my application where to go to get that username's details e.g. facebook.com/friends >> facebook.com/profile.cfm?userid=145. But I don't want anyone to have a username of 'friends' because I have a top level folder in my application with that name.

Comment: I'm not sure how to deal with adding a folder or file later that conflicts with an existing username :(

Comment: Perhaps you want to keep the two separate? `/index.cfm/user/myuser` and `/index.cfm/folder/myfolder`

Comment: There are probably simpler ways to accomplish your objective.  I added a url-rewriting tag to increase the number of people who might be able to suggest one.

Comment: Seems you have found yet another problem with writing your own framework that has been solved by just about every other framework out there. That fact that as the application goes on, you need to be careful of usernames when creating folders/files should clue you in to the fact that your solution is less than optimal.

Comment: You may want to rethink changing the username that is provided by the user. That is not a very good user experience. You could let the user know the username is taken, and maybe offer suggestions, but let them choose the username.

Comment: @ScottStroz yes I have allowed the user to try different variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your `'folder1,folder2,folderN'` into a getter function that returns a list of folders.

Then you can decide how to gather that list of folders.

Here are several ways I can think of:

- some global config file, or if you use coldbox, use coldbox's config.cfc settings
- do a `directoryList()` and figure it out dynamically, and optionally cache the result
- store the forbidden folder names in DB and check against the DB using sql

Comment: after thinking about it, I believe its best to have a table of Reserved Words in my database and check against that. Because there will be words that shouldn't be registered other than names of files and folders. For example profanities or trademarks.